looks like contextmenu option in monaco-editor/react not working with nextjs13?
import { editor } from 'monaco-editor';
import Editor, {Monaco, useMonaco, loader , EditorProps} from '@monaco-editor/react';//DiffEditor,
......
      <Editor
        //height="100vh"
        defaultLanguage="plaintext"
        defaultValue={!fileContent?"":fileContent}
        keepCurrentModel={true}
        beforeMount={handleEditorWillMount}
        onMount={handleEditorDidMount}
        onChange={handleContentChange}
        options={{
          lineNumbers: 'off',
          contextmenu: true,       
          roundedSelection: true,
          cursorStyle: "line",
          automaticLayout: true,
          selectOnLineNumbers: true,
          wordWrap: "off",
          fontSize: 18,
          minimap: {
            enabled: false,
          },
          suggest: {},
        }}
      />
 

as snippet from my nextjs project show above i want to turn on/off the "contextmenu" option to enable/disable the default monaco editor's contextmenu ,but nothing showed or changed except the brower's context menu pop when i right  click in mocaco editor area.
and i also found some demo in codesandbox as  follows:
https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-usage-forked-il8kt?file=/src/App.js
https://codesandbox.io/s/monaco-editor-contextmenu-oni1f?file=/src/index.tsx
they're working ,but none of them embeded into nextjs.
any one can help me,
dependencies are list below:
    "@monaco-editor/react": "^4.6.0",
    "monaco-editor": "^0.44.0",
    "next": "^13",
    "react": "^18",

